# Breadcrumb not registering in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have following route.

```
Route::get('pages/{name}', 'FrontendController@getPage')->name('frontend.pages');
```

And I am registering breadcrumb using following.

```
Breadcrumbs::register('frontend.pages', function($breadcrumbs,$pageTitle)
{

$breadcrumbs->parent('Home', URL::to('/'));
$breadcrumbs->push($pageTitle, route('pages',$pageTitle));
});
```

putting it in blade file like this

```
{!! Breadcrumbs::renderIfExists('frontend.pages','About Us') !!}
```

When I am trying to access "frontend.pages" 
    it is saying "Route[pages] not defied"

Any help would be great !

Answer (score 0):

Did you already register its service provider to the `config/app.php`?

Please recheck if everything is configured correctly. You may refer to its documentation [here](https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs#getting-started).

Comment: Yes. it is registered. but now error is different. it saying route not defined

Comment: try this:

 `$breadcrumbs->push($pageTitle, route('pages', ['name' => $pageTitle]));`

Comment: I got it worked by this
     $breadcrumbs->push($pageTitle, URL::to('pages',$pageTitle));

Thank you for your time. really appreciate it. :)